# Distributing deck to 13 players

Tags: combinatorics

> If 13 players are each dealt four cards from a 52-card deck, what is the probability that each player gets one card of each suit?

**My attempt:** Consider a four-block grid for each player[ like (__,__,__,__)], assigned diamond, spade, club and heart for first, second and so on. There are $13!$ ways to fill the first blocks. Same for second, third and fourth blocks. So, favorable outcomes are $(13!)^4$. The total number of ways of distributing $4$ cards to $13$ players are $52!/(4!)^{13}$ [arranging 52 cards, then for each of the 13 players, the order in which each of them receives the cards doesn't matter as long as the cards remain same. So we divide it by $4!$ for each of the players].
 So, the probability is $(13!)^{4}×(4!)^{13}/52!$.

Am I missing something?

Thank you!

Comment: The answer is $\frac {(13)^4} {\binom {52} {4}}.$

Comment: Why there are $13!$ ways to fill the first block instead of $\binom {13} {1}$ many ways?

Comment: Your calculation looks right to me.

Comment: @Dbchatto67 I am filling the first block of all the 13 players with one diamond card each. So, there are 13! ways to fill all the first blocks.

Comment: @Dbchatto67 - you are answering a different question, i.e. prob of a specific player getting $4$ cards of different suits.  The OP question is prob of _every_ player getting $4$ cards of different suits.